# Consecutive numbers on list

Tags: python, list, function

I have a list and want to show this list with consecutive numbers like;
1.Test
2.Hello
3. Bye

I use **enumerate(list,1)** function and get variables like 1Test, 2Hello 3Bye

are there any function or way in python to get dotted (consecutive) numbers for a better-ordered list?

Comment: Surely you can figure out how to construct a string which has a dot in it like `'1.Test'` given the ingredients `1` and `'Test'`.  What exactly is the question? What have you tried in your efforts to use `enumerate`?

Comment: `enumerate` yields tuples like `(1, "Test"), (2, "Hello"), ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
items = ['test','hello','bye']
for x, y in enumerate(items,1):
    print(f'{x}.{y}')
```

Your output will be

```
1.test
2.hello
3.bye
```

Comment: Thanks but I already did with the print function, It is not what I'm looking for. I want to assign them as a list variable.